# Expand circle box shadow and width height with animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

i would like to make animation which increases circle box shadow and its width and height.

What i want to do it circle box shadow and circle width height increase smoothly before adjusting to its actual width height it should expand bit more

I am able to done bit, but animation is not smooth.

What exactly i want to do is.

Here is fiddle

```css
 .circle{
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
     border-radius: 75px;
     background: #74E2BF;
     position:absolute;
     top:50px;
     left:150px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 25px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 25px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 25px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
     opacity:0;
}

.circle.animated {
     -webkit-animation: expand 2.5s 1 ease ;
     animation: expand 2.5s 1 ease;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     transform: scale(0.1);
     opacity:1;
}

@keyframes expand {
     0% {
         -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         transform: scale(0.001);
         opacity:1;
    }
     25% {
         -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 105px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 105px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 105px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         transform: scale(0.001);
         opacity:1;
    }
     50% {
         -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 105px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 105px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 105px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         transform: scale(0.001);
         opacity:1;
    }
     60% {
         -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 45px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 45px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 45px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         transform: scale(1.3);
         opacity:1;
    }
     75% {
         -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 25px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 25px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 25px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         transform: scale(1);
         opacity:1;
    }
     100% {
         -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 25px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 25px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 25px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         transform: scale(1);
         opacity:1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle animated"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve can be done more easily with a cubic-bezier timing funcion

You can play with the values of this funcion (and see graphically the one that I used)  [here](http://cubic-bezier.com/#.3,1.59,.7,1.52)

By the way, box-shadow has been suported prefix-free for a long time now.

```css
.circle{
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
     border-radius: 75px;
     background: #74E2BF;
     position:absolute;
     top:50px;
     left:150px;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 25px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
     opacity:0;
}

.circle.animated {
     animation: expand 2.5s 1 cubic-bezier(.3,1.59,.7,1.52);
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     transform: scale(0.1);
     opacity:1;
}

@keyframes expand {
     0% {
         box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         transform: scale(0.001);
         opacity:1;
    }
     100% {
         box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 25px rgba(116,226,191,0.3);
         transform: scale(1);
         opacity:1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle animated"></div>
```